# For Hyperledger Fabric production deployments what is the recommended number of kafka nodes and orderer nodes?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have recently been able to deploy a production environment for Fabric and I am looking to find what should be considered for deploying a Fabric network in production. Is there any considerations I need to take when deploying the orderers and kafka nodes? IE number of nodes and configurations. I cannot find much information on production grade Fabric networks.

Comment: You might want to try the Raft implementation, as Kafka is famous for the disk utilization. I am still not able to figure out how to cut down the storage requirements :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the Hyperledger Fabric documentation here [Docs » Bringing up a Kafka-based Ordering Service](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kafka.html)

> Let **K** and **Z** be **the number of nodes in the Kafka cluster and the
> ZooKeeper ensemble** respectively:
>
> - **At a minimum, K should be set to 4**. (As we will explain in Step 4
>   below, this is the minimum number of nodes necessary in order to
>   exhibit crash fault tolerance, i.e. with 4 brokers, you can have 1
>   broker go down, all channels will continue to be writeable and
>   readable, and new channels can be created.)
> - **Z will either be 3, 5, or > 7. It has to be an odd number** to avoid split-brain scenarios, and larger than 1 in order to avoid single point of failures. **Anything beyond 7 ZooKeeper servers is considered an overkill**.

**Update 14 Nov 2020**
Please note that Hyperledger has deprecated the use of Ordering Service Network based on Kafka. Usage of Raft Ordering Service is recommended for production.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this guide [Bringing up a Kafka-based Ordering Service](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kafka.html), I configured 4 kafka nodes for production.